# Version control for Magento

Tags: git

Currently we don't use version control for our Magentoshops. Normally we use Subversion/SVN, but when a colleague installed magento, he said it would be too many files, too much trouble with SVN. Our magento installation has 120.000 files in 40.000 folders. That means 40.000 subfolders for SVN, plus the files inside there.

We do have backups for the last 30 days, and as I have copies of the installation in a local VM, I have those snapshots and can go back one year. But for both it's trial and error finding something useful (although the snapshots really are super).

I'm thinking about installing GIT, maybe even only using a local repository. I understand it only has one .git file in the root, so we don't get thousands of files and subfolders.

Can I do this locally without messing the server up too much? What do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do use Git with much success. We move the files `.htaccess` and `app/etc/local.xml` as well as the folders `media/` and `var/` outside the directory, replace them with a symlink and version everything.
Git itself has a lot of files but they are all located within a single .git folder. We never had problems no matter the number of files.

Comment: `app/etc/local.xml`, don't forget that one. It shouldn't be versioned.

Comment: Can you explain why local.xml should not be versioned?

Comment: Of course we do the same for app/etc/local.xml. I forgot to mention it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @rxt because it holds db password.

Comment: Why do you ignore .htaccess and the complete media and var folders? Isn't the product cache in media enough? And in var I do ignore a bunch of folders like cache, session and report, but not all. Different modules install files in here and I would want them to be versioned.

Comment: The content of these files/folders can vary from environment to environment. That's we we move them outside the versioned folder but version the symlink. The `var/` folder is meant to contain data that can deleted anytime. Extensions which put important files there (which won't be generated again automatically) are not coded according to best practices. If your project demands it you are free to version parts of `var/` of course but I'd try to stay away from it. We never had to do that.